# How to divide a period in columns

Tags: postgresql, time, case, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a query where the first column shows the list of the companies and the other 3 columns their revenues per month. This is what I do:

```
WITH time_frame AS
  (SELECT date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '0 week'),
  
  
  time_frame1 AS
  (SELECT date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '1 month'),
  
  time_frame2 AS
  (SELECT date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '2 month')


select table1.company_name,

            (CASE
               WHEN  table2.date_of_transaction = (SELECT * FROM time_frame2) THEN sum(table2.amount)
               ELSE NULL
           END) AS "current week - 2",
           
              (CASE
               WHEN  table2.date_of_transaction = (SELECT * FROM time_frame1) THEN sum(table2.amount)
               ELSE NULL
           END) AS "current week - 1",
           
           
       (CASE
               WHEN  table2.date_of_transaction = (SELECT * FROM time_frame2) THEN 
 sum(table2.amount)
               ELSE NULL
           END) AS "current week - 2"




from table1
join table2 on table2.table1_id = table.id
where table1.company_joined >= '04-20-2019'

group by 1
```

When I execute the table this comes out: Error running query: column "table2.date_of_transaction" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 15: WHEN table2.date_of_transaction = (SELECT * FROM time_frame) TH... ^

Do you have any ideas on how to solve it? Thank you.

| company name | month1 | month2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | £233 | £343 |
| name 2 | £243 | £34 |
| name 3 | £133 | £43 |

Comment: Try deleting `group by 1`

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify the statement by using the `filter()` operator

```
select t1.company_name,
       sum(t2.amount) filter (where t2.date_of_transaction = date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '2 month'),
       sum(t2.amount) filter (where t2.date_of_transaction = date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '1 month'),
       sum(t2.amount) filter (where t2.date_of_transaction = date_trunc('month',NOW()))
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
where t1.company_joined >= date '2019-04-20'
group by t1.company_name;
```

If you really want to put the date ranges into a CTE, you only need one:

```
with dates (r1, r2, r3) as (
  values 
    (date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '2 month',
     date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '1 month',
     date_trunc('month',NOW()))
)
select t1.company_name,
       sum(t2.amount) filter (where t2.date_of_transaction = d.r1),
       sum(t2.amount) filter (where t2.date_of_transaction = d.r2),
       sum(t2.amount) filter (where t2.date_of_transaction = d.r3)
from table1 t1
  cross join dates d
  join table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
where t1.company_joined >= date '2019-04-20'
group by t1.company_name
;
```

The CTE `dates` returns a single row with three columns and thus the cross join doesn't change the resulting number of rows.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  What do you mean by "filter"? it is not recognized as a function in Postgresql

Comment: @RMolok: then you are using an outdated Postgres version

Comment: ok thanks, I think I solved using your answer and case when as a filter per each month